# Android Parse.com Unable to remove an item from Array field in both installation and User object

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've two array fields in my parse app one in Installation object named as "subscriber" and other in User object named as "SubsUser".

I've been trying to remove an item from both arrays by using this code...

```
  user.getList("SubsUser").remove(item);

  user.save();

  installation.getList("subscriber").remove(item);
  installation.save();
```

but even after using this code the items are visible on parse dashboard, it seems both my tables are not being updated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use put method to let ParseObject aware data is dirty.

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
List<Object> list = user.getList("SubsUser");
list.remove(item);
user.put("SubsUser", list);
user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "saved in background");
        if (e == null)
            //ok
        else
            //something else went wrong
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I myself solved the problem, i was using incorrect code
the write code to remove an object or collection of object from a parse array is

```
     List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
     list.add(item);
     user.removeAll("SubsUser",list);
     user.save();
     installation.removeAll("subscriber",list);
     installation.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution too, with a dialog

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogo_si_no);
        dialog.setTitle("La Lista");
        Button btnAceptar = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSi);
        Button btnCancelar = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnNo);
        TextView lblMensaje = dialog.findViewById(R.id.lblMensaje);
        lblMensaje.setText("¿Deseas eliminar este evento de tus favoritos?");
        dialog.show();
        btnAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) view.getParent();
                TextView lblObjectId1 = (TextView)layout.getChildAt(0);
                final String objectId = lblObjectId1.getText().toString();

                final ParseQuery<ParseObject> qFavoritos = ParseQuery.getQuery("favoritos").whereEqualTo("usuarioId",sharedpreferences.getString("globalUserId","0"));
                try {
                    List<ParseObject> resultado = qFavoritos.find();

                    final String id = resultado.get(0).getObjectId();
                    qFavoritos.getInBackground(id, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(final ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {

                                List<Object> lista = object.getList("eventos");
                                lista.remove(objectId);
                                object.put("eventos",lista);
                                object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "saved in background");
                                        if (e == null) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "favorito eliminado");

                                            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, EventosActivity.class);
                                            activity.startActivity(intent);

                                        }else{
                                            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                                        }
                                    }

                                });




                            }else{
                                Log.d(TAG,e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });


                }catch (Exception ex){
                    Log.d(TAG,ex.getMessage());

                }

            }
        });

        btnCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```